# Karma error: Cannot set property 'beforePreactivation' of undefined

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, ngrx, ngrx-router-store

I am trying to test a component in my Angular 5 app, which uses the `@ngrx/router-store`, and I was having problems with `state` being undefined in this selector:

```
import * as fromRouter from '@ngrx/router-store';

export const selectRouter = (state: AppState) => state.router;

export const selectUrl = createSelector(
  selectRouter,
  (state: fromRouter.RouterReducerState<RouterStateUrl>) => state.state && state.state.url // <--- state here is undefined
);
```

To overcome this problem, I tried adding the following imports in my TestBed-generated module:

```
imports: [
  RouterModule.forChild(wizardRoutes),
  StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, {metaReducers}),
  EffectsModule.forRoot([MyEffects, WizardEffects]),
  HttpClientModule,
  StoreRouterConnectingModule.forRoot() // <--- this makes it happier
]
```

Now, however, I receive the following error in the Karma test browser window:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'beforePreactivation' of undefined
>   at StoreRouterConnectingModule.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@ngrx/router-store/@ngrx/router-store.es5.js.StoreRouterConnectingModule.setUpBeforePreactivationHook (http://localhost:9878/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@ngrx/router-store/@ngrx/router-store.es5.js:169:1)

There is little or no information about testing the router store in the official docs, and I have been unable to find anything on Google.

I know I haven't provided an enormous amount of code, so please let me know what else you need to see and I will add it.

Answer (score 0):

To wire up the `Router`, you need to import the router via `forRoot` instead of `forChild`.

And indeed, you have to import `StoreRouterConnectingModule.forRoot` to be able to use the router reducer of NgRx.

Try using:

```
imports: [
  RouterModule.forRoot(wizardRoutes),
  StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, {metaReducers}),
  EffectsModule.forRoot([MyEffects, WizardEffects]),
  HttpClientModule,
  StoreRouterConnectingModule.forRoot()
]
```